# How have they simplified this function?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I have been trying to figure out how the following has been simplified, but I am getting nowhere with it. Anyone have any ideas?

$9(n/3)^{5/2}$ to $(1/3)^{1/2} f(n)$

It is given that $f(n) = n^{2.5}$.

Comment: Neither algorithms nor computer-science seem like appropriate tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
9\left(\frac{n}3\right)^{5/2}&=9\left(\frac13\right)^{5/2}n^{5/2}\\\\
&=3^2\cdot 3^{-5/2}f(n)\\\\
&=3^{2-5/2}f(n)\\\\
&=3^{-1/2}f(n)\\\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^{1/2}f(n)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$9\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^{5/2} = 9\cdot \left(\frac13\right)^{5/2} n^{5/2}$$ $$=9\cdot\dfrac{1}{3^{5/2}} f(n)$$ $$= \dfrac{3^2}{3^2\cdot3^{1/2}}f(n)$$ $$= \frac{1}{3^{1/2}}f(n)$$ $$=\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{1/2} f(n)$$